# Keep only values from a string

Tags: r, regex

Having a df like this:

```
df_in <- data.frame(x = c('x1','x2','x3','x4'),
                     col1 = c('http://youtube.com/something','NA','https://www.yahooexample.com','https://www.yahooexample2.com'),
                     col2 = c('https://google.com', 'http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321','NA','https://google.com/text'),
                     col3 = c('http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321', 'http://google.com?id=1234','NA','https://bbcnews.com/search'),
                     col4 = c('NA', 'https://www.youtube/com','NA', 'www.youtube.com/searcht'))
```

in col1, col2 and col3 how could be possible to keep only the cell with contain in them the "google" or "youtube" or "bbc" otherwhise make the cell NA?

Example of expected output:

```
   x                          col1                           col2                          col3                    col4
1 x1  http://youtube.com/something             https://google.com http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321                      NA
2 x2                            NA http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321     http://google.com?id=1234 https://www.youtube/com
3 x3  NA                             NA                            NA                      NA
4 x4 NA        https://google.com/text    https://bbcnews.com/search www.youtube.com/searcht
```

Comment: You mean contain that in the domain right? How about something like `http://www.something.com/google`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` to change the columns 'col1' to 'col4', with `str_detect` check whether it contains 'google' or 'youtube' or 'bbc' and replace the other elements with `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df_in %>%
     mutate_at(vars(col1:col4), funs(ifelse(str_detect(., 
                "google|youtube|bbc"), as.character(.), NA)))
```

-output

```
#    x                         col1                           col2                          col3                    col4
#  1 x1 http://youtube.com/something             https://google.com http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321                    <NA>
#  2 x2                         <NA> http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321     http://google.com?id=1234 https://www.youtube/com
#  3 x3                         <NA>                           <NA>                          <NA>                    <NA>
#  4 x4                         <NA>        https://google.com/text    https://bbcnews.com/search www.youtube.com/searcht
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `lapply` with replace:

```
cols <- c("col1","col2","col3","col4")
df_in[,cols] <- lapply(df_in[,cols], 
                       function(x) replace(x, !grepl("google|youtube|bbc",x ), NA))

df_in
#   x                         col1                           col2                          col3                    col4
#1 x1 http://youtube.com/something             https://google.com http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321                    <NA>
#2 x2                         <NA> http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321     http://google.com?id=1234 https://www.youtube/com
#3 x3                         <NA>                           <NA>                          <NA>                    <NA>
#4 x4                         <NA>        https://google.com/text    https://bbcnews.com/search www.youtube.com/searcht
```

That is to search anywhere in the string. If you wanted to just make sure the domain was `"google|youtube|bbc"` you could change the `grepl` to something like:

```
grepl("(google|youtube|bbc).com", test_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

URLs can be awkward in their parsing. I would recommend the library `urltools` for parsing and a `grepl` to find the domains of interest (assuming you are interested in those words being found in the domain), i.e.

```
library(urltools)

#Extract the domain
domain(df_in$col1)
#[1] "youtube.com"  "na"    "www.yahooexample.com"  "www.yahooexample2.com"
```

To apply it to your problem, then

```
df_in[] <- lapply(df_in, function(i) replace(i, !grepl('google|youtube|bbc', domain(i)), NA))



 x                         col1                           col2                          col3                    col4
1 <NA> http://youtube.com/something             https://google.com http://www.bbcnews.com?id=321                    <NA>
2 <NA>                         <NA> http://www.bbcnews2.com?id=321     http://google.com?id=1234 https://www.youtube/com
3 <NA>                         <NA>                           <NA>                          <NA>                    <NA>
4 <NA>                         <NA>        https://google.com/text    https://bbcnews.com/search www.youtube.com/searcht
```

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

Use a combination of [`sapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) and [`grep()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) to change the elements that don't fit your desired pattern to NA.

```
df[ , 2:5 ][] <- sapply( X = list( df$col1, df$col2, df$col3, df$col4 )
                          , FUN = function( i ){
                            # store elements that meet the condition
                            condition <- grep( pattern = "youtube|bbc|google"
                                                , x = i
                             )
                             # replace elements that don't meet the condition with NA
                             i[ -condition ] <- NA
                             # return i to the Global Environment
                             return( i )
                          }
                        )
```